# Grunt Watch not running Compass as secondary task

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-compass

I am trying to include a call to `grunt-contrib-compass` in my `watch` task, but it's not registering any saved changes to my .scss files.  `grunt compass` works fine, and `grunt watch` records all other changes to *.php as expected.  What's a guy doing wrong here?

gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
    grunt.initConfig({
        compass: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    config: 'config.rb'
                } //options
            } //dev
        }, //compass
        watch: {
            options: { livereload: true },
            scripts: {
                files: ['/scripts/*.js'],
            }, //scripts
            sass: {
                files: ['/_sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['compass:dev']
            }, //sass
            html: {
                files: ['*.php']
            } //html
        } //watch
    }) //initConfig
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch');
} //exports
```

And just for kicks, my config.rb:

```
css_dir = '/css'
sass_dir = '/_sass'
output_style = :nested
```

Answer (score 0):

Your leading '/' in all your paths are throwing you off, remove them (both from gruntfile and config.rb):

```
watch: {
    options: { livereload: true },
    scripts: {
      files: ['scripts/*.js'],
    }, //scripts
    sass: {
      files: ['_sass/*.scss'],
      tasks: ['compass:dev']
    }, //sass
    html: {
      files: ['*.php']
    } //html
} //watch
```